# Software to create folder structure

Tags: windows, file-management

When we create a project, company or whatever we use a folder structure.

Is there a software that can allow us to create a folder structure like that of visio and then export the folder structure out and also update existing folder structure with an NEW folders that are added to the folder structure?

I do not want to just copy and paste, but rather a use a software to help and create a few templates.

Thanks

Comment: Should be possible to do with a script. Can you update the question and add details about the exact folder structure you want initially?

Comment: This is the thing. I know that I could use a script... However I was wonder if there is another way to make life easier. For example, you can me a folder structure in VISIO.... would be great if you could export the structure out to real folders.

Comment: I would create the templates in explorer and use rsync to copy them somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Here is the appropriate solution I have found using VBA scripting Microsoft Excel

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/800-create-folders-based-on-excel.html